# how to create sequential consecutive variables to push into an array using a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm declaring variables, word_1, word_2, word_3, word_4 and word_5, by asking the user to input a word per each prompt(). I'm then pushing the variable into an array. next, I'm checking the total characters in the array, which should be a minimum of 25 letters. If the user has not inputted 5 words with their total equal to or larger than 25, I want to prompt them again and create a variable that continues the existing naming pattern, then push that into the existing array and check the total characters again and so on until 25 or more characters has been established.

The assignment calls for using an array to hold the variables.

```
    var word_1 = prompt("Please enter a word.");
    var word_2 = prompt("Please enter a word.");
    var word_3 = prompt("Please enter a word.");
    var word_4 = prompt("Please enter a word.");
    var word_5 = prompt("Please enter a word.");

    var wordList = [];
    wordList.push(word_1);
    wordList.push(word_2);
    wordList.push(word_3);
    wordList.push(word_4);
    wordList.push(word_5);


    var total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    var wordLength = wordList[i].length;
    total = total + wordLength;
```

Comment: This is a programming question, it would be much easier if you posted your code rather than explain in plain English what your code does.

Comment: @Claire, okay. thank you. I will keep this in mind in the future. I don't have the code to post, other than code that does not work because I don't know how to do what I requesting. I feel like there is an easy solution that Im just over looking.

Comment: @JReal well post what you've done so far and what specifically you are having issue with. A lot of folks around here are more than willing to help walk you through assignments, especially if you show you're trying.. not so much just do it for you.

Comment: @Crayon Violent, I added the code I have thus far. thanks. Sorry for any confusion. I'm extremely new to JS and to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** OP just edited the question to add a requirement to use array instead, but I left my original answer at the bottom in case it would help anyone.

---

If the requirement is to use an array, then you would not need to assign variables at all. You could simply use the array, push into it and iterate as you need to. I would also assume that the assignment wants you to get comfortable with working with arrays.

This would work as a quick solution, but since this is your assignment it would be best for you to understand it and write your own solution:

```
let array = []

// function to return length of all characters in array
const countFunc = array => {
    return array.join('').length
}

// Keep asking user for input until the count is at least 25
while (countFunc(array) < 25) {
    array.push(prompt("Enter string"))
}
```

The resulting array would look like:

```
["some string", "another string"...]
```

---

**Original answer:**

It would be better if you used an object instead of creating variables for each prompt, as you are unsure of how many variables you need, from a minimum of 1 to maximum of 25 (or more, if you allow submission of empty strings "")

By using an object, I mean:

```
let obj = {}, index = 0

// Your function to count the total number of characters
const countFunc = obj => {
    ...
}

// Keep asking user for input until the count is at least 25
while (countFunc(obj) < 25) {
     obj[index] = prompt("Enter string...")
     index++
}
```

The result of your object will look like:

```
{
    0: "some string",
    1: "another string"
    ...
}
```

Then you can access each value by its index when you need it.

Note: You do not have use a numeric index as keys for your object, but in your case an incrementing index if easier instead of using random words, timestamp or random numbers.

Your count function would look something like:

```
const countFunc = obj => {
    let totalLength = 0
    // Loop through all keys in object,
    // add the length of each string
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        totalLength += obj[key].length
    })
    return totalLength
}
```

Alternatively you could use a reduce function to get the total length from the object keys as well.

Comment: I mean.. you can do the exact same thing with an array and its indexes..

Comment: @Abu Uzayr, thank you for the help. the assignment calls for using arrays, which is why I'm struggling. I already created a for loop to check the total character count of the array. I just need to figure out to create variables that follow the existing naming scheme and check the total again within the loop.

Comment: @JReal I updated the answer. You keep mentioning the need to create variables though, and I'm not sure where that would fit in in an array..

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all of you for the assistance and patience. @AbuUzayr, I see your point and I realize the error in my thinking. You rock.

Comment: No problem! Could you accept my answer if it helped you? Thanks!

Comment: This seems overly-complicated